# Reflect changes in claims of token that already sent after customer made some update

Tags: openid-connect, identityserver3

One of our clients - client A uses Javascript implicit client library to authenticate with us, in the id_token that we sent back to them contains first_name, last_name information of the authenticated customer, which both value in the id token are then used for displaying on the client pages.

We also has another openid client B which customer can manage their profile information e.g. to update their first name and last name, etc...

**Problem**

After customer made changes on their profile via client B (e.g. updated first name, etc..), the new value doesn't reflect on pages of client A, that is because the id token was original received is not reflected with new value.

is there a way that the client B can notify OP side to regenerate token, which then force client A to renew the token ? or you think this is completely madness? any suggestion for resolving this issue please?

Ming

Comment: Sounds like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37577995/1395123

Comment: Thanks Brock, that is a very similar issue as we are facing, difference is we don't expect our customers update their first/last name that often, but we do want to find a solution to support it if someone does updated their first name. Both of our clients are separate websites as well as our OP, so the solution you referenced there can be very complex in our situation as they don't share same caching infrastructure, and it could become tricky on when/how/notifying to decache data.

Comment: i can see it will work but resolving a less often scenario by introducing another complex system sounds a bit overkill to me. can you think of any other possible way?

Comment: in essence what's in the token is a cached value from the OP. that's a classic comp sci problem and not specific to security.